# If condition in for loop for two variable

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a data file named st and it contains many lines of variables and each line of them has the specific name.
I want to select two specific lines of those data with names and assigned them to values. My codes are as bellow and it just selects one line of my data and ignores the second 'if' condition.
Does anybody have an Idea?

```
with open(input("ENTER YOUR STATIONS COORDINATES FILE NAME : "), 'r') as st:
    ST = input("ENTER YOUR STATION NAME :").upper()
    ST1 = input("ENTER YOUR 00 STATION NAME :").upper()
    with open(input("ENTER YOUR COORDINATE FILE NAME :"), 'r') as f1:
        with open(input("ENTER YOUR OUTPUT FILE NAME :"), 'w') as f2:
            print(ST, ST1)
            for lines in st:
                values = lines.split()
                NO = int(values[0])
                X = float(values[1])
                Y = float(values[2])
                Z = float(values[3])
                Code = values[4]
                if Code == ST:
                    X1 = float(values[1])
                    Y1 = float(values[2])
                    print(X1, Y1)
                    if Code == ST1:
                        X00 = float(values[1])
                        Y00 = float(values[2])
                        print(X1, Y1, X00, Y00)
                        st.close()
```

A part of My input data:

> ```
>  1      1505.114      5528.524   1060.572   S1
>  2      1283.787      5442.505   1084.851   S3
>  3      1189.962      5272.845   1108.214   S3t1*
> ```

My code output as is below:

> ```
> ENTER YOUR STATIONS COORDINATES FILE NAME: st
> ENTER YOUR STATION NAME:s3t2
> ENTER YOUR 00 STATION NAME:s3
> ENTER YOUR COORDINATE FILE NAME:h.dat
> ENTER YOUR OUTPUT FILE NAME:h.out
> S3T2 S3
> 1059.056 5230.141
> Process finished with exit code 0*
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use multiples if statements without using else or elif statement. The compiler looks for two things in 'if statements' to give output: first, if the condition has met; second, if the condition has not met. You have given two consecutive 'if statements' without providing what happens if the condition isn't met. So use else statement to give compiler the second thing it's looking for.

Comment: When I add 'elif' or 'else' for the next condition, it won't work at all, and I don't know why?

Comment: May be you're typing the 'else statement' inside the first 'if statement'. Don't write else or elif statement inside the if statement, write it at same indentation level as the first 'if statement'.

Comment: Exactly I did it as you say. Highly appreciate if you can tell me how do I can assign two variable in one loop.

Comment: Suppose you have two data sets D1 and D2,  and you want loop through both at the same time. Its actually pretty simple. Just do this   for i,j in zip(D1,D2):  values of D1 will go in 'i' and values of D2 will go in 'j'.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance and comments, but as I said, my first parameter in the second line of the data file and my second parameter in the third line, and I can't put them on to zip command. I want to assign the first and second parameters in each line to the fourth parameter(Corresponded to name).

Comment: Can somebody help me?